# How to execute ./adb shell bmgr run programmatically?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I´m trying to perform backup using the google backup services.  The only way it works is when I open the shell and execute this command: " ./adb shell bmgr run ".  Is there a way of doing this programmatically ?...something to call that calls this command?

My code:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("nom", et1.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("noml", et2.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("mdl", et3.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
    bm.dataChanged();
 // some code here to call (./adb shell bmgr run) programatically?
```

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm having the same problem, running the adb commands seems to work.

Comment: Nope, disabled the backup trials using this method...  I use preferences, files, parse DB....

Answer (score 0):

Bmgr is only intended for testing. In your application code, you would request backup via the BackupManager.

See the documentation at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#RequestingBackup

Comment: Thanks,  that's what I'm doing with bm.dataChanged() ;  It doesn't run immediately,  I think it doesn't work well.. Haven't test it with hours passing before uninstalling and see if it worked though...